# how to override Drupal path from another module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want my module to override the path was set by another module

Example:

Module A has register a path:

```
$menu['node/%id/test'] = array(
    'title' => 'Test',
    'page callback' => 'test_A',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'test_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
)
```

Now I create module B and register the same path.

```
$menu['node/%id/test'] = array(
    'title' => 'Test',
    'page callback' => 'test_B',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'test_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
)
```

Every request to this path

> www.mysite.com/node/1/test

will route to module B not A.

What is the best way to override an existing path was set by other module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use an alter hook, [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7):

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%id/test']['page callback'] = 'test_B';
}
```

Since you're just modifying an existing menu router definition, you only need to declare the part you want to change (e.g., the page callback function name). Note also `$items` is passed by reference, so you don't need to return anything.