# Drupal page callback in menu_alter. How to use callback before redefining

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In module User:

```
  $items['user/%user/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_profile_form', 1),
    'access callback' => 'user_edit_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
  );
```

In my module:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
   $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_can_edit_user';
   $items['user/%user/edit']['access arguments'] = array(1);
   $items['user/%user/edit']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_user_edit_page';
}


function MYMODULE_user_edit_page($account){
   if(my_condition){go to page... }
   else { use callback from module User }
}
```

How to use default page callback from module User if **my_condition** in function *MYMODULE_user_edit_page* is not TRUE ?

Comment: "return $items;" is missing in the MYMODULE_menu_alter

Comment: Your code will work. Check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837048/how-to-override-drupal-path-from-another-module

Answer (score 0):

What about...

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_can_edit_user';
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access arguments'] = array(1);

  $current_callback = $items['user/%user/edit']['page callback'];

  $items['user/%user/edit']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_user_edit_page';
  $items['user/%user/edit']['page arguments'][] = $current_callback;
}


function MYMODULE_user_edit_page($existing_callback = NULL){
   if(my_condition){go to page... }
   elseif (!empty($existing_callback)) {
     $existing_callback($account);
   }
}
```

Comment: $existing_callback($account); ? 
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ...

Comment: Ah the default page callback for that path doesn't have a parameter, I thought it accepted the account. The edit should sort it